# Random Redirects - Spyware/adware?

Tags: windows-7, virus, spyware, adware

**PROBLEM**

I am noticing that half of the websites I go to randomly redirect to bestprizedraw.com (this is not a link for your own safety). However, I have scanned my computer several times and have found no adware, spyware, registry links, etc. So, what gives?

---

**CURRENT SOLUTIONS**

For antivirus, I have used Microsoft Security Essentialsm Katpersky's TDSSKiller, and Malwarebyte's Anti-Malware.
I have also tried a System Restore and I have NOT visited any strange sites lately. My router's and my computer's DNS are both set to auto, and to use Google's DNS as a backup.

---

**MSCONFIG**

List of Startup items I find suspicious:

- *Intel (R) Common User Interface* by Intel Corporation (this item is listed three times)
- *HpqSRmon Application* by Hewlett-Packard
- *Apple Push* by Apple Inc.

List of Services I find suspicious:

- *IconMan_R* by Realsil Microelectronics Inc.
- *PMBDeviceInfoProvider* by Sony Corporation
- *VCService* by Sony Corporation
- *VSNService* by Sony Corporation
- *VUAgent* by Sony Corporation
- *Wireless PAN DCHP Server* (unknown publisher)

---

**ADDITIONAL DETAILS**

I have port 25565 and port 25567 forwarded because I play Minecraft.

Comment: Did you also check your DNS settings?

Comment: I would bet lunch that you *do* have spyware, The symptoms you describe are classic. What scanning software did you use?

Comment: Did you also check the DNS settings _in your home router_?

Comment: See my post here if you suspect an infection....http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533#157533

Comment: Can you run nsolookup command and tell what is the default DNS server set right on your PC?

Comment: `IPCONFIG /ALL` shows that the default DNS is set to 192.168.0.1

Comment: 192.168.0.1 is an IP of your router?

Comment: Yes, I can access it by connecting to http://192.168.0.1

Comment: I would advise you to run [ESET SysInspector](http://www.eset.com/us/download/utilities/) to obtain a complete snapshot of your PC for further examination.

Comment: Have you already found something suspicious? I would double check all entries matching level Unknown(5)-Critical(9).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this link for information on this redirect

http://www.guforums.com/showthread.php?p=312800

Basicly websites run ads on their pages, the ad agency chooses what ads to run, and this is a particularly bad one.

I imagine once people complain enough to the webmasters they will complain to the ad agency and they will stop running this ad.

Comment: That doesn't seem like the problem.. I'm experiencing this mostly, but not specific to, the Minecraft Wiki (www.minecraftwiki.net) and Yahoo Answers.

Comment: Yep, it turns out that it was some of the websites hosting the advertisements. I have alerted the admin and they have handled it.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might have had some form of malware at some point (and possibly still do). You can try the steps described [here](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc). The steps under "What to do after restoring" should help if you are sure there is no more malware.

Specifically you can:

- Check your hosts file (\%systemroot%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts)
- check your DNS settings (should usually be auto but can try google DNS if you like)
- Your proxy settings in control panel/IE should be disabled.

Comment: In my HOSTs file, every line has a # sign preceeding it. My DNS settings are set to default and Google's as a backup. I do not use IE, and I don't have any proxy settings on either.

Comment: @Jeffrey is this problem consistent across all web browsers that you try (IE/Firefox/Chrome...) or is there just one browser that has this problem?

Comment: I don't really use IE, and I don't have Chrome, I mostly use Firefox.